# Further processing information in Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I built a simple image uploader in Django with a progress bar. When the image was initially uploaded, I did indeed see the progress bar correctly update to 100%.  However, I also do further operations on server side (like scale, save in different locations, create thumbnail etc).

Is there a way to let client side know that 'processing image' is progressing, and to report this via another progress bar, for instance?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please post some code what you had tried so far?

Comment: Do you process the image synchronously?

Comment: [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically your Django app could periodically refresh itself and maintain state on the server, updating a progress indicator as it detects what stage the process is up to, but given you tagged JQuery and Ajax I suspect you're looking to do this progress updating on the client side.

If you are passing the image processing from one view to the next in Django via multiple HTTP requests then in JQuery you would be sending multiple Ajax requests to 'progress' the image through to completion. 
As each request completes and returns something to the client side, your JQuery can grab the completion status, update your progress bar accordingly and then submit the next request in the sequence to Django as the next request.
If your Django app simply does everything in the background with one HTTP request to the server, then there's nothing your client side can do to check the progress (that I'm aware of) unless the Django app can expose it's progress in a different view somehow and your client-side can periodically check that to see where it's at.